# ST_NumInteriorRings produces no result in a geometry that has inner rings?

Tags: postgis

I am working in Postgres 9.5. This is my table:

```
 gid    | integer                 | not null default nextval('mytable_gid_seq'::regclass)
 geom   | geometry                |
 county | character varying(1000) |
```

The `geom` field was created by running `ST_Union` over a MultiPolygon field in another table.

If I run `SELECT geom FROM mytable WHERE county='Manchester'` and then export the results to GeoJSON and open them in QGIS, the resulting polygons look like this.

[image]

Now I want to find the number of interior rings in the geometry for Manchester:

```
SELECT ST_NumInteriorRings(geom) FROM mytable WHERE county='Manchester';
```

However, it produces an empty result. I don't understand this, since I can clearly see holes in QGIS.

I've also tried `ST_NumInteriorRings(ST_Multi(geom))` but that doesn't produce a result either.

What am I doing wrong? (What I would ultimately like to do, in case it helps, is find the area of the internal holes.)

Comment: Have a look at the actual geometry with SELECT ST_AsText(geom) FROM mytable WHERE county='Manchester'; Perhaps it helps you further.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to specify what is actually returned -- "no result" and "empty result" are not clear descriptions the way "no rows" and "a row with a NULL value" would be. Try altering the query to select "county,ST_AsText(geom),ST_IsValid(geom)," plus your expression and include the full output.

Answer (score 3):

[ST_NumInteriorRings](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_NumInteriorRings.html) operates only on `POLYGON` geometries, returning `NULL` for any other type, including `MULTIPOLYGON`:

```
SELECT ST_NumInteriorRings('MULTIPOLYGON (((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 0)))');
-- NULL

SELECT ST_NumInteriorRings('POLYGON ((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 0))');
-- 0
```

If your geometries are MultiPolygons that each contain a single polygon, you can get the number of interior rings with `ST_NumInteriorRings(ST_GeometryN(geom, 1))`.

Comment: Or in the OP's case ST_Area(ST_GeometryN(geom, 1)), etc. I guess you could use generate_series in conjunction with ST_NumInteriorrings to do this cleanly.